# Netlify functions (AWS Lambda) example "hello" Golang function: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: go, aws-lambda, netlify

I'm trying to get Netlify Functions work with Go.
First, I tried cloning official example repo (https://github.com/netlify/aws-lambda-go-example) and it worked.

My problem is, I have a Hugo website which require `hugo` build command and I don't know how to build Hugo with `hugo` and Go source files with `make build` (like in example repo) - I think it could solve the problem, but I couldn't find relevant docs describing this option.

So my next step was to manually compile Go function file and put it into `functions` folder.

source file (from the example above):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func handler(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: 200,
        Body:       "Hello AWS Lambda and Netlify",
    }, nil
}

func main() {
    // Make the handler available for Remote Procedure Call by AWS Lambda
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

I used instruction available at https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go#building-your-function to compile Go binary:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o hello hello.go
zip hello.zip hello
mv hello.zip ./functions/hello.zip
```

This was pushed to Git and therefore deployed to Netlify. So far so good, my function appeared in Netlify UI.

[image: hello.js]

But when I requested the function URL, I got error message:

```
    {
  "errorMessage": "Invalid or unexpected token",
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "",
    "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token",
    "createScript (vm.js:80:10)",
    "Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:616:28)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:11:18)"
  ]
}
```

This is function log from Netlify:

```
1:18:16 AM: hello invoked
1:18:17 AM: Syntax error in module 'hello': SyntaxError
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ELF
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
1:19:02 AM: hello invoked
1:19:03 AM: Syntax error in module 'hello': SyntaxError
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Also, function name appears to be `hello.js` in Netlify UI - I don't know if it should be like that. It seems to me that AWS thinks it's Javascript instead of Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have not tested a zipped go function on Netlify.

If you do not want to do the manual build in this case, you can inline your build commands on Netlify deploy.

Add a build command that does both builds for the project.

```toml
[build]
  command = "make build && hugo"
  functions = "functions"
  publish = "public"
[build.environment]
  # Change this path with the path to your repository
  GO_IMPORT_PATH = "github.com/netlify/aws-lambda-go-example"
```